# How to connect two points with a curved line in GNUplot?

Tags: gnuplot, line, draw, tikz

Its basically what the question says. I know that using tikz in latex it would be something like:

\draw[thick,dashed] (0,0) to [out=15,in=165] (1,0)

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a misunderstanding how lines in gnuplot work. They are always directly connecting points. So you have to ways of faking it:

1) adding additional points and connecting them to "pretend" to have a curved line

2) define a function with the curve you want and plot it over the points (in xrange of point 1 to 2)

Answer (score 0):

What I had to do is to great a .tex file with everything else a needed and then, in the .tex file I add the "\draw[thick,dashed] (0,0) to [out=15,in=165] (1,0)". But I wish I could know how to do it using GNUplot itself.